# How to click class of class with Selenium, Python?(Crawling microsoft website)

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I want to crawling microsoft website to remove my photos.

I want to click all photos (the maximum is 100 photos)and click delete button and repeat almost 4-5times.

And the "ItemCheck" class is the button to choose photo.

But there are another "ItemCheck" class irrelevant to the specific photos.

The difference of two "ItemCheck" class is ancestor.

So I want to find "List-cell" class first and find  "ItemCheck" class among the "List-cell" class.

How can I resolve this? 
I used pythone and sublime.

I tried with "find_elements_by_css_selector" as the code, but the "row" was empty! =>[ ]

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

EMAILFIELD = (By.ID, "i0116")
PASSWORDFIELD = (By.ID, "i0118")
NEXTBUTTON = (By.ID, "idSIButton9")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="mypath/firefoxdriver_win64/geckodriver.exe")
browser.get('https://login.live.com')

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(EMAILFIELD)).send_keys("mymail")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(PASSWORDFIELD)).send_keys("mypassword")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(NEXTBUTTON)).click()

browser.get('https://onedrive.live.com/?v=photos')
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

#Click class="ItemTile-rowCheck" which the ancestor is class="List-cell"
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="List-cell"]') #bring div elements which have class="List-cell"
print(elements)
for i in range(0,24) : #temporory
    print(i)

    row = elements[i].find_elements_by_css_selector('.ItemTile-rowCheck') #find .ItemTile-rowCheck among elements[i]
    print(row)
    print(row.click)
```

The result is this when this code run ended.

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="647f1105-2da6-47f0-870b-de097648cd21")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="442a5f3e-4301-4a80-b7f4-f5fba96a56e9")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="2654aa45-61ae-4360-995f-3d2b68eef4d8")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="ad471298-e830-4e51-8d3c-41addf085851")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="ca88ef30-6d7b-427f-9f9e-2240e803a15e")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="db1ae4c3-e80f-469d-89ee-5eea778b7913")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="0ac74651-1c1e-40b3-9ea2-2df41302ea06")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="12759c61-6c85-4d68-8dcb-ed75744ae2bb")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="a1bcd428-5f1d-44b5-bc7f-94d367c7e31f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="e3b2e76d-d17e-4c00-a3fd-0b96f721037a")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="311d9527-4175-48eb-9447-d9dfdbc55bf8")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="6cd98ae1-6209-4fd1-a1e4-0faf744c59a1")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="f5d0a102-b9a9-4be5-9c71-58927c2d4e21")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="344d3cf5-3d68-4ef6-b0e1-f62ed4005b69")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="7369e37f-2b4b-4c73-ae1b-72a92ee590a5", element="f8777f86-d581-4697-96df-6c2b28490eed")>]
0
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath\Desktop\firefox.py", line 36, in <module>
    print(row[0].click)
IndexError: list index out of range
[Finished in 71.3s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Although you're using Sublime Text to run the code, this is not a Sublime Text question because all Sublime is doing is telling the `python` interpreter to run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop as shown below

```
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='List-cell']//*[@class='ItemTile-rowCheck']")
print('Total rows ' + str(len(elements)))
for i in range(1,len(elements)) : # iterates through all elements
    print(i)
    row = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='List-cell']//*[@class='ItemTile-rowCheck']")[i]
    print(row)
    print(row.click)
```

Answer (score 0):

@supputuri

Thanks to you, I got how to use xpath! Thank you so much! 
By the way I did this way also which select a date covered whole photos.
But this way just selected even arrays, [0],[2],[4]..
If range start from 1, selected odd arrays, [1],[3],[5]..

```
#Before
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='od-AllPhotosHeader-check can-select']")
print('Total rows ' + str(len(elements)))
for i in range(0,len(elements)) :
    print(i)
    row = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='od-AllPhotosHeader-check can-select']")[i]
    row.click()
```

So I changed code like this, 
And this worked! 
I want to know that what was unable to select whole number with first code?

```
#After
elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='od-AllPhotosHeader-check can-select']")
print(elements)
for i in range(0,len(elements)) :
    print(i)
    row = elements[i]
    row.click()
```

I am so sorry to reply like this, but the comment is too limit to add code.